# msbuild xmlupdate delete node in web.config

Tags: msbuild, msbuild-task

How do I use MSBuild Community Tasks to delete a node in web.config. I can update a node using XmlUpdate task but I cannot delete a node. Any ideas.

Comment: Funny, i never noticed that before.  Maybe try using PowerShell from MSBuild to do what you need?  Or submit a patch with a custom 'XmlDelete' task! :)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The XmlUpdate task can do it. I am using the nightly build from 11/30/2010.

```
 <XmlUpdate
      XmlFileName="web.config"
      XPath="/configuration/appSettings/add[@key='setting2']" 
      Delete="true" />
```

The XmlFile task of the  [MSBuild Extension Pack](http://msbuildextensionpack.codeplex.com/) can also do it:

```
 <XmlFile
      TaskAction="RemoveElement"
      File="web.config"
      XPath="/configuration/appSettings/add[@key='setting2']" />
```